# Sortable, draggable, lovable, squeezable, huggable

Tags: jquery-ui

I have an unordered list that needs to be sortable, so

```
$('#myID ul').sortable({        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'   });
```

works.  Now, the problem is that the user also wants to be able to drag the elements...

I don't think I can have it sortable, AND do

```
$('#myID li').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
})
```

Can I?